# Pivoting on multiple columns ang grouping by two columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot

I have a table that shape of data in it looks like image below and I have also included some script to easily create and populate it for experiments.

[image]

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temptable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temptable;
CREATE TABLE #temptable ([RiskName] VARCHAR(50)
                       , [RiskName_Change] VARCHAR(50)
                       , [PriceVal] DECIMAL(8, 2)
                       , [PriceVal_Change] DECIMAL(8, 2)
                       , [Portfolio] NVARCHAR(200)
                       , [benchmark] NVARCHAR(200)
                       , [EffectiveDate] DATE);
INSERT INTO #temptable ([RiskName], [RiskName_Change], [PriceVal], [PriceVal_Change], [Portfolio], [benchmark], [EffectiveDate])
VALUES ('OilPrice', 'OilPrice_CHANGE', 120.00, 5.50, N'PORT45', N'SP500', N'2022-06-02T00:00:00')
     , ('StocksCrash', 'StocksCrash_CHANGE', 340.00, 600.00, N'PORT45', N'SP500', N'2022-06-02T00:00:00')
     , ('SupplyChain', 'SupplyChain_CHANGE', 710.00, 23.45, N'PORT45', N'SP500', N'2022-06-02T00:00:00')

     , ('OilPrice', 'OilPrice_CHANGE', 110.00, 15.50, N'PORT45', N'SP500', N'2022-06-01T00:00:00')
     , ('StocksCrash', 'StocksCrash_CHANGE', 240.00, 500.00, N'PORT45', N'SP500', N'2022-06-01T00:00:00')
     , ('SupplyChain', 'SupplyChain_CHANGE', 400.00, 123.00, N'PORT45', N'SP500', N'2022-06-01T00:00:00')

     , ('SupplyChain', 'SupplyChain_CHANGE', 300.00, 82.40, N'PORT45', N'SP500', N'2022-05-31T00:00:00')
```

I think what I need is two `pivots`? but I am not quite sure. But the end result that I need should look like this below: Notice that each row is based on `Portfolio` and `EffectiveDate` and then if there are risks or changes to risks, those are converted to columns. Also note that in reality it could be 20 of these risks, I just added three risks for demonstration.

```
Portfolio | EffectiveDate | Becnhmark | OilPrice | OilPrice_Change | StocksCrash | StocksCrash_Change | SupplyChain | SupplyChain_Change |
PORT45    | 2022-06-02    | SP500     | 120.00   | 5.50            | 340.00      | 600.00             | 710.00      | 23.45              |
PORT45    | 2022-06-01    | SP500     | 110.00   | 15.50           | 240.00      | 500.00             | 400.00      | 123.00             |
PORT45    | 2022-05-31    | SP500     | NULL     | NULL            | NULL        | NLL                | 300.00      | 82.40              |
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `PIVOT` which is very inflexible, you can use conditional aggregation.

> It's unclear what sort of aggregation you want? `SUM` `MIN` something else?

```sql
SELECT
  t.Portfolio,
  t.benchmark,
  t.EffectiveDate,
  OilPrice           = SUM(CASE WHEN RiskName = 'OilPrice'                  THEN PriceVal END), 
  OilPrice_CHANGE    = MIN(CASE WHEN RiskName_Change = 'OilPrice'           THEN PriceVal_Change END),
  StocksCrash        = SUM(CASE WHEN RiskName = 'StocksCrash'               THEN PriceVal END), 
  StocksCrash_CHANGE = MIN(CASE WHEN RiskName_Change = 'StocksCrash_CHANGE' THEN PriceVal_Change END),
  SupplyChain        = SUM(CASE WHEN RiskName = 'SupplyChain'               THEN PriceVal END), 
  SupplyChain_CHANGE = MIN(CASE WHEN RiskName_Change = 'SupplyChain_CHANGE' THEN PriceVal_Change END)
FROM #temptable t
GROUP BY
  t.Portfolio,
  t.benchmark,
  t.EffectiveDate
ORDER BY
  t.Portfolio,
  t.benchmark,
  t.EffectiveDate DESC;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fca0818080184c9331e63d97984b008f)

Comment: interesting. So you have for now hard coded those risks ( SupplyChain, etc ... ) . So in my final code I should do some dynamic sql because won't know what comes in that table for my risks names

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54351133/14868997 although I recommend you move that type of code to the application level, T-SQL is not good at that kind of thing

Comment: Unfortunately it is a SP inside a SSIS package that is going to do this. It is such a headache.  Thanks I will look at that link now.